# Set 2 permmissions for 2 different actions in ListCreateAPIView in django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am developing an end-point where users can get the categories and only admin can create them. I am using Django and DjangoRestFramework. More specifically I am using `ListCreateAPIView`.

Here is my code.

```
class TagView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, ]
```

**My Task**: I need to set two permission for list and create, they are `AllowAny` and `IsAdminUser`.

Any ideas or suggestions and answers are welcome. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [rest_condition](https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition) library. In your case, you can code like this:

```
...
from rest_condition import And, Or
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsPostMethod(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method.upper() == 'POST'


class IsSafeMethod(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method.upper() in ('OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'GET')


class TagView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        Or(
            And(IsPostMethod, IsAdminUser),
            And(IsSafeMethod, AllowAny),
        )
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`method_decorator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e3f6e18513224c8ad081e5a19da641f49b0b43da/django/utils/decorators.py#L53) in combination with [`permission_required`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e3f6e18513224c8ad081e5a19da641f49b0b43da/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L53) on top of your API class, like this:

```
@method_decorator(permission_required('permission_name'), name='method_name')
class TagView ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using custom permissions, It worked pretty well, and clean.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import SAFE_METHODS, BasePermission

class IsAdminOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return request.user.is_superuser
```